# Posicionar componentes verticalmente com GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

Criei um código em java para posicionar objetos na janela do tipo `JComboBox` e `JTextField` e quero que eles fiquem um em baixo do outro. O código que tentei é esse:

```
/*Biblioteca */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

class creator {

public static void main(String args[]){

 EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            /*Cria o layout*/
            GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            /* Gera os campos, tela, e configurações */
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
            JTextField texto = new JTextField();
            texto.setColumns(15);
            JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

            /* Cria as opções e configurações do JComboBox */
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o1");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o2");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o3");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o4");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o5");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o6");
            combo.addItem("op\u00e7\u00e3o7");

            /* Adiciona as coisas na tela */
            panel.add(texto);
            panel.add(combo, c);

            /* Configurações da janela */
            frame.setTitle("Layout");
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            /*seta como o arquivo fecha e sua visibilidade */
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
}
}
```

Comment: Não é a mesma duvida da outra? - `quero deixar eles no meio da janela sem estarem grudados na borda da janela e um no outro e sem que fiquem pegando a janela inteira`

Comment: não e cara eu consegui aplicar o layout mais não consegui deixar os botões um em baixo do outro e já pesquisei em milhares de lugares e ngm explica como faz isso.

Comment: Como não está? Eu fiz seu exemplo justamente baseando de la, tudo que se precisa para entender esse layout tem la.

Comment: eu entendi so que os botões não ficam um em baixo do outro.

Comment: Mas não fala nada disso no link. Ele explica como utilizar este layout.

Comment: então foi por isso que eu criei esse tópico para saber se e possível usando esse layout deixar 1 objeto em baixo do outro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Atualização

Descobri que não é necessário informar o posicionamento com `gridX` e `gridY` para posicionar 2 componentes em vertical. Basta alterar a classe conforme abaixo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PosicaoDeCompTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc1.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JTextField texto = new JTextField();
            texto.setColumns(10);
            panel.add(texto, gbc1);

            JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            combo.addItem("opção1");
            combo.addItem("opção2");
            combo.addItem("opção3");
            panel.add(combo);

            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

O [`gridwidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#gridwidth) serve para definirmos quantas células o componente precisa para ser exibido naquela linha, e ao passarmos a constante [`GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#REMAINDER), estamos definindo que este componente dever ser o ultimo da linha. No código acima, essa alteração força o layout a jogar o que vier após o campo de texto na próxima linha, fazendo com que o combo possa ser adicionado diretamente(sem configurar uma instancia de`GridBagConstraints`).

---

Apenas lendo o [link que havia lhe passado](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) eu consegui modificar o código para exibir os elementos verticalmente:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PosicaoDeCompTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc1.gridx = 0;
            gbc1.gridy = 0;
            JTextField texto = new JTextField();
            texto.setColumns(10);
            panel.add(texto, gbc1);

            JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
            combo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            combo.addItem("opção1");
            combo.addItem("opção2");
            combo.addItem("opção3");
            GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc2.gridx = 0;
            gbc2.gridy = 1;
            panel.add(combo, gbc2);


            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Destacando o que está explicado na documentação:

> **gridx, gridy**
>   Specify the row and column at the upper left of the component. The leftmost column has address gridx=0 and the top row has address gridy=0

Como este layout funciona como um grid, é possível definir onde cada componente vai ficar, quantas células do grid ele vai ocupar, dentre outros detalhes explicados no link, e com `gridx` e `gridy` você define as "coordenadas" do componente no grid, onde o primeiro representa a posição horizontal(coluna) e o segundo a posição vertical(linha) do componente no grid. Alterando a posição padrão da linha do combo para 1, ele já é exibido abaixo do campo de texto.

Outro detalhe: **nome de classe começa com letra maiúscula**, `creator` não segue a convenção do java.

Comment: era isso que eu tava tentando fazer deixar do jeito que vc deixou um objeto em baixo do outro.